How can I sync the postion of gameobject with unity mirror networking?
I have a player object with a NetworkIdentity commponent and 1. child object.
Thats my simple code which will run with a key press.
    [Command]
    void CmdTellServerToTellClientToChangePosBack(Transform trans) {
        RpcTellClientToMoveContainerBack(trans);
    }
    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcTellClientToMoveContainerBack(Transform tran) {
        if (tran == null) return;
        tran.position = Vector3.zero;
    }

Then I get this LogWarning Attempted to sync a Transform (Item Slot 1 (UnityEngine.Transform)) which isn't networked. Transforms without a NetworkIdentity component can't be synced. Why?
I tryed to moven an object and sync it to the other clients which end evertime with this logWarning.

what exactly are you passing in as trans? Sounds like that object doesn't have a network ID ...

(trans) is The Transform from a empty child gameobject

yeah then as said that is not possible .. you only can directly pass on a reference to an object that has an ID in the network so the receiver side knows what you are referring to ... Why do you need to pass the reference into the method rather than simply using a class field e.g. exposed to the Inspector?
